# Configuration Management Software for Linux for "harvesting" config-files

Tags: linux, puppet, cms, cfengine

Managing 50 servers manually, and been looking through the different cms for linux (cfengine,puppet,chef etc) It's use will primarily for CM for config-files.

Is there a cms out there that gather information from the existing servers? So i don't have to write class'es, recipies etc for each server, but automatically gets config-files from my server, so I can edit them centrally later?

Comment: How would it know which files and configurations are important?

Comment: It would be a list of files provided by the administrator. Looks like blueprint is the answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint) can generate Puppet or Chef configurations from your existing servers, if you want to *start* using one of those two tools.

Alternatively, [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/) will help you keep the whole of `/etc` in a VCS, if that's all you need (with a little bit of config, you could then keep the repositories somewhere central).

Answer (score 2):

Blueprint author here and it does *exactly* what you need. We like to say it reverse engineers a server - that is detects packages, source files and configurations tweaks, then packages it up in a reusable format. Check it out on github: https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint.